# React.js hot reloading not working on osx catalina

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm learning react.js
I'm using MacBook with osx Catalina. I was use HighSierra before. React.js hot reloading was work correctly on HighSierra but when I upgraded to Catalina, it wasn't work. Even when I refresh browser window, changes in project wasn't show. The only way to see changes on browser is stop react server and run again!
I researched a lot in the internet but I didn't find the solution. Please help me to solve this problem. I forced to use microsoft windows temporary but I can't carry two laptops (MacBook and another laptop for windows) with myself to work.
I give full disk access to vscode and terminal but the problem didn't solve. I also reinstall watchman with brew but the problem still.
**Note:** My node.js and npm is up-to-date.
Can you give me a useful solution?
Thanks

Comment: What is the file path to the project?

Comment: @MattCroak /System/Volumes/Data/HDD/Projects/React/[project directory]

Comment: Is it literally called [project directory] because that would definitely cause an issue I think. Hot reload is kind of buggy with special characters in the file name

Comment: Actual it is: /System/Volumes/Data/HDD/Projects/React/azshanbe

Answer (score 0):

Finally I downgrade my mac to OSX Mojave then problem solved!